# variables in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I need to create a family relationship using Prolog. I installed SWI Prolog on my laptop, and create a file with two variables just to get familiar with Prolog.
I did consult to import the file and thought I was good to go. However, when i tried to access the file, (for example: fname(x).) instead of returning the content on the fact, it's returning "true".

Answer (score 1):

Variable names in Prolog start with an [uppercase letter](http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/learn-prolog-now/html/node11.html#subsec.l1.vars). If your file contains

```
fname(adam).
fname(eve).
```

then you can call `fname` as follows:

```
?- fname(X).
X = adam ;
X = eve.
```

Note: the semicolon (`;`) is user input.

Comment: that's what I have in my file, but as you can see it isn't working properly. What am I missing?

Comment: i didnt realize it was a upper-case "X".

Comment: Please post your file, that makes it a lot easier to spot the error. Click the 01-button to format the contents.